# How to get the index of each increment in pandas series?

Tags: pandas

how to get the index of pandas series when the value incremented by one?

Ex. The input is

```
  A
0 0
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 2
6 3
7 4
8 4
```

the output should be: `[0, 1, 4, 6, 7]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Series.duplicated` and access the index, should be slightly faster.

```
df.index[~df.A.duplicated()]
# Int64Index([0, 1, 4, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

If you really want a list, you can do this,

```
df.index[~df.A.duplicated()].tolist()
# [0, 1, 4, 6, 7]
```

Note that `duplicated` (and `drop_duplicates`) will only work if your Series does not have any decrements.

---

Alternatively, you can use `diff` here, and index into `df.index`, similar to the previous solution:

```
np.insert(df.index[df.A.diff().gt(0)], 0, 0)
# Int64Index([0, 1, 4, 6, 7], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates('A').index.tolist()
[0, 1, 4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Great work, I thought it drops duplicates randomly.      
form docs, It keeps the first row of duplicated data by default  `keep=’first’ `

Comment: This is correct but keep in mind you return a new DataFrame just to access the index.

Answer (score 0):

This makes sure the second row is incremented by one (not by two or anything else!)

```
df[ ((df.A.shift(-1) - df.A) == 1.0)].index.values
```

output is numpy array:

```
array([2, 5])
```

Example:

```
#                                *        *  here value increase by 1
#                          0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 8, 3, 4, 4]})
df[ ((df.A.shift(-1) - df.A) == 1.0)].index.values
array([2, 5])
```